# How can I intercept encoded video data using ffmpeg with C?

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg

First of all, I hope you'll understand my poor english skill. I'll do my best to write question about it.

I'm currently developing some application. That application will captures desktop and encodes to MP4 video and send mp4 video data/chunks to another clients (all this process should run in memory not file). so another client should can play mp4 video/data/chunks that received from server.

so I used `avio = avio_open(...)` and reassigned write function as like `avio->write_packet = some_function`. but this way seems not "generate" mp4 file/chunk correctly. and It seems the original `write_packet` callback having actual logic that write packet to a file. but I don't want to write to a file. so I was thinking about it for a week but I did't getting any of idea about it.

so my question is: How can I **intercept** "encoded" video data that should processed by `avio->write_packet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hijack `avio_open`-provided aviocontext, that's bound to cause you troubles. If you want to provide custom AVIOContext, do so - use `avio_alloc_context` and provide your callbacks there. Use flag `AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO` to indicate that you did so (so this AVIOcontext won't be destroyed automatically when muxer closes).

Comment: I already tried to use `avio_alloc_context` too. but It won't provide correct video data. It won't even play with regular video player if I just do `fwrite(...)` to destination file. should I write extra data to destination file?

Comment: And it writes correct video file if you just use `avio_open` with some filename, right? If that's the case then maybe you just need to call `avio_flush` on your custom AVIOContext (instead of `avio_close` you'd usually call for `avio_open`ed context)